# Obtaining snapshots of TV shows programmatically like Google

Tags: google-search, freebase

If you look at the image, Google manages to extract images as well as structured data in relation to the show "CSI". I would like to understand where Google obtains this data from (freebase?) *as well* as where Google gets these *images* from. Is there an API we can use to obtain this data?

If freebase is used and someone can provide me with a sample query, it would be very much appreciated.

[image: the Google search results for "csi"]

Comment: Recommending services that provide data, like any other off-site resource recommendation, is off-topic for stack overflow.